# Is there anything we need to do for APPSEC-1079 SUPEE 6788?

Tags: magento-1.9, security, supee-6788

There is 4th SUPEE 6788 security notice :

*APPSEC-1079, addressing potential exploit with custom option file type*

> "This change will affect any customization that uses product custom
>   options to save information as a PHP object. Such an approach will no
>   longer be possible."

After installing the patch, do we need to do anything with this?

Comment: http://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details